# React Router changes the URL address but it renders another component - Material ui V. 5.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm having a headache with routing in react 18.0, I'm using `react-router-dom` v.5.0, and Material ui - 5.0. **The component Login doesn't render,** **instead another component is rendered "`CreateNotes`"**. The URL shows `/login`, and the component "CreateNotes" is rendered. All the routes are correct. Also when I click on another menuItem ("Banks") it goes to the correct route **`"/bancos"`**, but it still rendering the same component **"`CreateNotes`"**, with the route `"/bancos"` on the URL. Seems that is stuck on this route. I'll include only the necessary parts of the code that is very long. Thanks for your help. Summarizing: clicking on Logout (to render Login page) render "CreateNote" and the url shows `/login`. The same happens with clicking on Banks. Why?

APP.JS

```
import Notes from './pages/Notes';
import CreateNotes from './pages/CreateNotes';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Bancos from './pages/Bancos';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ Notes } />   
            <Link to="/create" component={ CreateNotes } />
            <Route exact path="/bancos" component={ Bancos } />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={ Login } />      
          </Switch>
        </Layout>       
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Links

```
<Link to="/login" style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "white" }}>
  <Button type="button" variant="text" 
 sx={{ bgcolor: "#1483dd", color: "#ffffff", mt:1, marginRight: 11 }}>
 {/* // onClick={() => { history.push('/login')}} didn't work */}
    Logout
  </Button>
</Link> 
// this link is at the app-bar menu
 
// The code below is in the Drawer:
 
const fileItems = [
  {
    text: 'Bancos',
    icon: <AccountBalanceRoundedIcon style={{color: '#e2e7ea'}} />,
    path: '/bancos',
  },
  {
    text: 'Centro de Custos',
    icon: <AttachMoneyIcon style={{color: '#e2e7ea'}} />,
    path: '/custos',
  },
  {
    text: 'Clientes',
    icon: <PeopleAltIcon style={{color: '#e2e7ea'}} />,
    path: '/clientes',
  },
]

<List dense>
  {fileItems.map((item) => (
    <ListItem 
      button 
      dense
      key={item.text} 
      onClick={() => history.push(item.path)}
      className={location.pathname == item.path ? classes.active : null}
    >
      <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={item.text} className='listItem'/> 
    </ListItem>
  ))}
</List>
// "/bancos" does not render
```

Comment: `<Link to="/create" component={ CreateNotes } />` I don't know why you are using link here. Change it to Route. `<Route exact path="/create" component={ CreateNotes } />`

Comment: All right Charchit , it worked fine with Route. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your  component usage is not intended. Did you mean to use **Route** ?

Link prop **component** is to customize the Link itself, not to render the entire page. Your Switch component should **only** render Routes.

As of right now it renders routes + your Link component that is actually rendering an entire **CreateNotes** page.

Comment: function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Router>
    <Switch>
    
    <Layout>
        <Route exact path="/" component={ Notes } />
        <Route exact path="/layout" component={ Layout } />
        <Route exact path="/create" component={ CreateNotes } />
        <Route exact path="/bancos" component={ Bancos } />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={ Login } />

    </Layout> 
  
   </Switch>
    </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: I made the change to Route, and everything is working fine. Thank you for your support. Best Regards.